# How to set a handleChange function with PUT HTTPS Method ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I am creating an admin control panel for a list page that displays a list of cards. The control panel gives the user an "edit" and "delete" button. They currently both work, but for the edit button, it does not add the newly added text.

[image]

The edit function is in HelpList.tsx and the code is as follows:

```
editProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "changed title",
        url: "changed Url",
        thumbnail: "changed thumbnail"
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }
```

The code for that card + modal tooltip with the form is in HelpCard.tsx and is as follows:

```
<div className="horizontalCard">
              <div className="innerCard">
                <div className="leftImage">
                  <img
                    className="Sprite"
                    onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
                    onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: true })}
                    src={this.state.thumbnail}
                    style={
                      this.state.tooManyRequests
                        ? { display: "none" }
                        : this.state.imageLoading
                        ? { display: "null" }
                        : { display: "null" }
                    }
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="rightText">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    {this.state.title}
                    <div className="cardButtons">
                      <Popup trigger={<button className="btn">Edit</button>} position="left center">
                        <form
                          onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                          id="videoCardEdit"
                          style={{ width: "auto", height: "auto" }}>
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Title:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardTitle" defaultValue={this.state.title}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>URL:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardURL" defaultValue={this.state.url}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardThumbnail" defaultValue={this.state.thumbnail}></input>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <button
                            className="btnConfirm"
                            style={{
                              float: "left"
                            }}
                            onClick={() => this.props.editProduct(this.props.id)}
                            id="confirmModalBtn">
                            confirm
                          </button>
                        </form>
                      </Popup>
                      <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteProduct(this.props.id)} className="btn">
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

So the issue is this, since Ihave set title, url and thumbail to "changed ... " in the editProduct function, when I click submit for the edit, it changes the thumbnail, url and title to the following:

[image]

So how would a handleChange function be applied to this in order for it to detect whatever changes I make to the input directly through the modal tooltip?

----------------------------EDIT---------------------------

HelpCard calling in the HelpList.tsx

```
<HelpCard
                    id={adminhelpcard.id}
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
                    editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}
                  />
```

Comment: to rephrase, you want to get the updated values from inside the Popup instead of the hardcoded values ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Yes that is correct

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I am trying to get the new values from the Popup to overwrite the values that're put in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the updated values, you can convert the inputs to [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

```
                          <div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Title:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardTitle" value={this.state.title} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({title: e.target.value})} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>URL:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardURL" value={this.state.url} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({url: e.target.value})} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label>Thumbnail URL:</label>
                              <input name="videoCardThumbnail" value={this.state.thumbnail} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({thumbnail: e.target.value})}></input>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <button
                            className="btnConfirm"
                            style={{
                              float: "left"
                            }}
                            onClick={() => this.props.editProduct(this.props.id, this.state.title,this.state.url,this.state.thumbnail)}
                            id="confirmModalBtn">
                            confirm
                          </button>
```

and in the edit product function,

```
editProduct(id: any,title:string, url:string, thumbnail:string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail //since the key and variable name are same
      })
    };

    fetch(apiUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }
```

PS: there are more optimal ways to do it, and for starters, you could send title,url and thumbnail as props to the component and manage its state from the parent. But the above solution would work within the scope of the question.

Comment: For the confirmModalBtn onclick (onClick={() =>
                              this.props.editProduct(
                                this.props.id,
                                this.state.title,
                                this.state.url,
                                this.state.thumbnail
                              )
                            }), It is saying "Expected 1 arguments, but got 4. ts(2554)

Comment: Also, I have edited the question to include my HelpCard component that's used in HelpList. and the "editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}" now returns the error  "Type '(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(id: any) => void'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context?: any): HelpCard', gave the following error.
    Type '(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(id: any) => void'.ts(2769)"